# Login failed, database issue

Tags: laravel, database, react-native

Application is developed on the native frontend and the backend is using laravel.

Live Application is crashing again and again

I already implemented database back on live because I thought that my DB is hacked, but again facing the same issue
[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. Check connect database (.env)
2. Try run: php artisan migrate:refresh, php artisan migrate
3. Check database if exist this table